# How do handheld folding fans create airflow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, fan

Google provides no answers to this question. Google only tells how it cools but not how it it creates airflow. Could someone explain how handheld folding fans create an airflow despite only moving back and forth?

Comment: if they are moving back and forth there is an induced back and forth flow too,

Answer (score 1):

The motion of the handheld fan causes the air pressure around the fan to fall as the fan pushes air molecules away from the space around it.The surrounding air which is at a higher pressure then flows into the space around the fan.This is what causes the air flow.